# Send mail with attachment using the MIME Mail module

Tags: 7, emails

I am not able to send mails with an attachement using the [MIME Mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module.
There isn't munch documentation about this module, but [some people](http://drupal.org/node/1389504#comment-5617230) claim they have successfully used the module, and sent a mail with an attachment.

I've enabled and successfully configured:

- [Mail System](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem)
- [Mime Mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail)
- [Swift Mailer](http://drupal.org/project/swiftmailer)

I think I configured the modules correctly.

[image: screenshot]

No mail with attachement is delivered. I call `drupal_mail()` in a cron job with the following code.

```
drupal_mail('mymodule', 'notice', $user_email, $lang, $params, $admin_email);
```

It should invoke any `hook_mail()` implementations, which it does, but without the attachment.

```
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $data['user'] = $params['from'];
  $account = $data['user']->name;

  $file_content = file_get_contents('some/file/path');

  $attachments = array(
     'filecontent' => $file_content,
     'filename' => 'example-' . $account,
     'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
   );

  switch($key) {
    case 'notice':

      $langcode = $message['language']->language;
      $message['subject'] = 'example submission from '. $account;
      $message['body'][] =
        '<p>'. $account .' has submitted an example.</p>';
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $attachments;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: concept behind this workflow is that a file link attached to mail(file uploaded to server and its link given).

Comment: Eum... What's the point you're trying to make?

Answer (score 4):

The solution I've found is to use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to attach the file to the email after it's generated and before it's sent. The key to that is making an array of details about your attachment and adding that to $message['params']['attachments'].

hook_mail will send mail, but if you're using another program to send (Swift Mailer or [PET](https://drupal.org/project/pet)), then I believe you'll need hook_mail_alter to alter the mail instead of sending it yourself.

I also suggest using the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/group/file/7) ([also this](https://drupal.org/node/555118)) to keep track of your file. That's not required, however, just provide the necessary info.

```
function myhook_mail_alter(&$message) {

  print "message id: {$message['id']}\n";

  // if this email is one of the ones I want to alter:
  if (!empty($message['id']) && (preg_match('/^message-id-set-by-formmail[\d]{1,2}/', $message['id']))) {

    // $message['params']['body'] is a single string, not an array
    $result = preg_match('/\[my dumb string with node id# (\d+)]/', $message['params']['body'], $matches);

    print "Message body: \n {$message['params']['body']} \n\n Matches:\n";
    print_r($matches);

    if (!empty($matches[1])) {
      $file_id = $matches[1];
      $my_pdf = file_load($file_id);
      $original_attachments = $message['params']['attachments'];
      // $original_attachments is an array of associative arrays, each bearing details about an attachment.
      // Add an associative array about this desired attachment.
      $my_attachment = array(
        'filecontent' => file_get_contents($my_pdf->uri),
        'filemime' => $my_pdf->filemime,
        'filename' => $my_pdf->filename,
        'filepath' => NULL,
      );
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $my_attachment;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My working Drupal 7 solution with module MimeMail without invoking hook_mail():

```
// Load attachment.
$file = file_load($fid);

$to = 'something@email.com';
$from = 'something@email.com';
$subject = 'Invoice ' . $file->filename;

$module = 'mimemail';
$token = time();

$message = array(
  'id' => $module . '_' . $token,
  'to' => $to,
  'subject' => $subject,
  'body' => array('something text...'),
  'headers' => array(
    'From' => $from,
    'Sender' => $from,
    'Return-Path' => $from,
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  ),
  'params' => array(
    'attachments' => array(
      0 => array(
        'path' => file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($file->uri)->realpath(),
        'filecontent' => file_get_contents($file->uri),
        'filename' => $file->filename,
        'mime' => $file->filemime,
        'encoding' => 'base64',
        'disposition' => 'attachment',
        'list' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

$system = drupal_mail_system($module, $token);
$message = $system->format($message);

if ($system->mail($message)) {
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should work, good luck!

```
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $data['user'] = $params['from'];
  $account = $data['user']->name;

  $file_content = file_get_contents('some/file/path');

  $attachments = array(
     'filecontent' => $file_content,
     'filename' => 'example-' . $account,
     'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
   );

  switch($key) {
    case 'notice':

      $langcode = $message['language']->language;
      $message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
      $message['subject'] = 'example submission from '. $account;
      $message['body'][] =
        '<p>'. $account .' has submitted an example.</p>';
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $attachments;
    $system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
    // Format the message body.
    $message = $system->format($message);
    // Send e-mail.
    $message['result'] = $system->mail($message);

    if($message['result'] == TRUE) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
    }
    else{
        drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not     sent.'), 'error');
    }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Mail has a nice documentation on this, check [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1590190) out. And below I did a small custom function to grab the full uri path of the attachments.

```
/**
 * Send an e-mail.
 */
function test() {

  //load the file by fid
  $file_one = file_load(1);

  //create the file details manually.
  $file = new stdClass();
  $file->uri = file_create_url($file_one->uri);
  $file->filename = $file_one->filename;
  $file->filemime = $file_one->filemime;

  if (!empty($file)) {
    // set parameters
    $params = array(
    'subject' => $subject,
    'body' => $body,
    'to' => $to,
    'cc' => $cc,
    'files' => array($file)
    );
  }
  // Send message
  $message = drupal_mail('singtel_kms', 'send', $to, language_default(),$params);

  // Check the email result array to make sure an email was sent.
  if(!empty($message['result'])) {
     drupal_set_message(t('Your email has been sent.'));
  } else {
     drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem with the application. Please send again or contact administrator.'), 'error');
  }
}
```

In your hook_mail()

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_mail().
 */
function modulename_mail($key, &$message, $params) {

  switch($key) {
    default:
        $text[] = t('<strong>Hi</strong>');
        $text[] = t('<p>This is an e-mail.</p>');

        if (isset($message['params']['files'])) {
            $message['params']['files'][] = $params['files'];
        }

        $message['subject'] = t('Test');
        $message['body'] = $text;
        break;
    }

}
```